# Setting Bar Button Item color in a custom navigation bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I created a custom navigation bar and a right navigation button using the XIB. This works fine. But I need to to customize the tint color of the right navigation button. At the moment this tint color is the same color as tint color of navigation bar. I need a different color for this right button. Is there any way to change this color?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not to my knowledge, the button inherits the tint color of the navigationBar. What you can do is set a customView for the navigationItem:

This is how you set it with one of the SDK's buttons:

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(shareButtonHandler:)];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:shareButton];
[shareButton release];
```

Instead you can do it like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(customButtonHandler:)]];
```

To use an image you made in photoshop etc.

There is als an `initWithCustomView:UIView` or `initWithTitle:NSString` you can use.

Sorry no "one-line solution" :)

Comment: Yes this is the closest answer. No other way to do this infact. Thank you RickiG.

Answer (score 14):

In iOS 5 there is 'appearance' feature:

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:YOUR_COLOR];`

Comment: Yes this is a very old thread. In the old OS it was not that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.x

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : Color.primaryActionColor], for: .normal)
```

Comment: The problem here is that every UIBarButtonItem is going to have that color. To avoid this, you can do : UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIToolbar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(...)

Answer (score 0):

If you have navigation bar button item with custom view you should convert to **UIButton** first:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView as? UIButton
```

Then you can add the attributes of **UIButton** such as:

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1), for: .normal)
```