# Setting UIBarItems to red/blue colors

Tags: iphone

How are UIBarItems set to blue and red color?

What properties are there for the items to allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one property you can set to give a UIBarButtonItem a blue color is to set the *style* property to UIBarButtonItemStyleDone.

You could set the tintColor property on your UIToolBar which will also tint any UIBarButtonItems in the bar.

Comment: +1 for Simon  as this is the right way without doing any custom implementation for button...

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely. What is the property to get the red button, like delete.

Comment: The red color you probably need to subclass or use a custom view for.  I don't know of a buit-in way to have a button with a color that is not blue or the tint color of the toolbar it is on.  The answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518617/setting-bar-button-item-color-in-a-custom-navigation-bar) has some code in it that might give you a starting point.