# iOS 6, How to tint UIBarButtonItem white icons?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have UIBarButtonItems in my app with a light color background, and I wanted to tint the icons with a darker color, instead of the standard white.

Like this:

[image]

I was able to tint text using

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor blackColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];,
```

but I can't figure out how to change the icon colors.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have a UIBarButtonItem with a colored image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835260/can-i-have-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-a-colored-image)

Comment: +1. Never noticed this thing.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `UIButton` with your custom image, then create a `UIBarButtonItem` with the `UIButton` as a custom view:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]; // Tint this image programmatically
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
```

Note that this is mainly for iOS 6 and below. In iOS 7+ you get this behavior for free with `tintColor`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might work in the navigation bar:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

And of course, you can also change the **whole** tint in the storyboard options (not on my mac, so can't tell you exactly where)

Answer (score 0):

```
[myBarButton_name setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor yellowColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but 1: I believe it will only change text color (not icon color), since it's basic the same thing I did, written in a different way; 2: I'd rather make global changes than a button-by-button basis.

Comment: you mean you want to change color of UIBarButtonItem ?

Comment: @Guilherme  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518617/setting-bar-button-item-color-in-a-custom-navigation-bar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677703/change-uibarbuttonitems-color

Comment: No, I want to change the color of the icon/image inside the button.
Like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AUPfh.png.

Comment: Best way is create custom button add it.. i tried to find your solution on google .. but can not able to find out :(

Comment: @iPatel You do not need a custom button to colorize a standard `UIBarButtonItem`. Just set the button's `tintColor`.

Comment: @rmaddy - but using `tintColor` color.. we can change color of `UIBarButtonItem` not image color.. OP only want to change color of image of built-in `UIBarButtonItem`.. such like  http://i.stack.imgur.com/AUPfh.png

Comment: @iPatel I know what the OP wants. I do this in my own app. Under iOS 6, in a toolbar, setting the bar button item's `tintColor` only changes the color of the icon, not the whole button. In a navbar it does change the whole button, not the icon.

Comment: @rmaddy - yes.. you are right because i tried (tintColor) with barButton of navbar..so..